# Rewrite boolean expression with XOR

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, xor, boolean-expression

I am new to logic design, and am trying to teach myself. I understand that XOR indicates the output will be 0 only when the inputs are the same. Additionally, I understand that given two inputs called A and B, ((~A AND B) OR (A + ~B)) equates to A XOR B.

I am trying to learn how to convert a boolean expression without XOR into a boolean expression with at least one XOR and perhaps other gates.

Say I have the boolean expression:  (~A AND ~B AND ~C) OR (A AND B AND C). I am attempting to convert this expression into one that contains at least one XOR.

However, I am having a hard time understanding where to place the ~C and C, and operations. I tried the following:

((~A AND B) OR (A AND ~B)) AND (~C AND C) but it is not equivalent.

((~A AND B) OR (A AND ~B)) OR (~C OR C) but it is not equivalent.

((~A AND B) OR (A AND ~B)) OR (~C AND C) but it is not equivalent.

((~A AND B) OR (A AND ~B)) AND (~C OR C) but it is not equivalent.

What I am missing here? Can anyone please explain how to take the original boolean expression, and implement it with XOR?

I love teaching myself, and learning new things, but this is driving me crazy after hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A form with plenty `XOR` operations is the [ANF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form) (algebraic normal form, Zhegalkin normal form, or Reed–Muller expansion):

```
~((A AND B) XOR (A AND C) XOR (B AND C) XOR A XOR B XOR C)
```

I've got this asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%20and%20b%20and%20c%20or%20not%20a%20and%20not%20b%20and%20not%20c).